# What is the correct method for getting a client to purchase a Craft license?

Tags: license

What is the recommended way from P&T to get a client to purchase a license for Craft CMS? It doesn't actually say how on the website.

If you give a user literally all the permissions Craft has, when they log in to an unlicensed Craft Pro install, they'll see this warning at the top:

[image: warning bar]

If they click Resolve, they get taken to /admin/plugin-store/upgrade-craft and see this error:

[image: error message]

The only way I can see for a client to purchase a license is to make them a full Admin, which goes against everything the permissions are set up for. I don't ever want to make a client a full site administrator because they can easily break stuff.

**Context:** I'm working on behalf of a larger design agency, and the end client is liable for purchasing their own licenses. The design agency is not buying it on their behalf.

Comment: Probably not the solution you're looking for but why not just have Craft as part of the quote and purchase it for them? Saves them faffing around and ensures it gets licensed.

Comment: As soon as I wrote that I thought about the charge year 2 and realised client-side billing is a good idea.

Comment: Wait, you can buy it from the plugin store, just scroll to the bottom?

Comment: Yep, you're right - there's recurring billing, and I don't want the clients coming back to me later about it if I can keep it all in their court. I had totally missed the block at the bottom of the plugin store though!

Answer (score 1):

I normally pay for the license and bill back to the client, turning off automatic renewal. After purchasing, if the client wants to have access to their license, I have them create a Craft ID account and transfer the license to them.

Comment: Thanks Jeremy - I used to do this with personal clients too, but I prefer to get them to buy their own licenses. I've updated the question with context here though; I'm working on behalf of a design agency, and the agency isn't buying licenses on behalf of the client, so the end client needs to buy their own license here.